# Configuration files error after trying to deploy a Django App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple (no database) website made with Django that i'm trying to deploy on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I got a WARN error : "Configuration files cannot be extracted from the application version toulouse-psy-emdr-v2. Check that the application version is a valid zip or war file."

I don't find any explanation about it. I followed a tutorial for the .ebextensions file, my zip file is valid. The rest is successful.
The application doesn't work and I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I found people talking about it, but no clear solution. Does anybody have ever had that error ? What can I do ?

I ckecked my .ebextensions file and the django.config inside. It looks like this :

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: cabinet_psycho.wsgi:application
```

Comment: How does your zip file structure look like? Do you also see any other error?

Comment: Hello, no that was the only error at the end. I coulndn't lose more time, switched to fly.io.